# Launch legacy desktop app, even if Windows 8 Start Screen is foreground window?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# console app that is trying to start a legacy desktop app.  I want this legacy desktop app to start and display even if the current foreground window is the Windows 8 Start Screen or a Start Screen application.

If I start the legacy desktop app, it will launch, but it launches behind the Windows 8 Start Screen and does not show.  If I click on the "Desktop" tile, I see the app has launched.  But I want the app to launch /AND/ show.

Is there a way to both start a legacy desktop application and show it, even if the Windows 8 Start Screen is showing??

Any ideas??

Comment: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/8529357f-3ff8-4c83-baaf-5215ca9cc14a

Comment: How about without UIAcess="true"?

Comment: That's only half the story, you also have to buy a certificate.  Apps forcing their preference on the user just isn't very appropriate.  The user will pick himself, either by using an add-on from a company like Stardock or by using the upcoming Windows 8.1 that will make it an option.

Answer (score 0):

#### Show desktop

*From https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/c-show-desktop/*

Using C# we can write code to Show Desktop. Same effect as clicking on “Show Desktop” icon on Taskbar.

First, add reference to “Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation” from COM tab of “Add Reference” dialog

```
Shell32.ShellClass shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
shell.MinimizeAll();
```

Or use this approach: [Minimizing all open windows in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785054/minimizing-all-open-windows-in-c-sharp)

#### Check if Windows 8 start screen is active

[IMetroMode::IsLauncherVisible in C# via pInvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009999/imetromodeislaunchervisible-in-c-sharp-via-pinvoke)